# How to Sort after position a product collection?

Tags: magento-enterprise, collection, products, filter, ee-1.14.2.2

This is how I get my collection:

```
$_productCollection = $this->getItemCollection();
```

This is how I get the products:

```
foreach ($_productCollection as $_product):
     echo $_product->getData('position');
endforeach
```

At the moment I get my products randomly. Can I sort by **position**  ? if yes how can i do it ? thx

This is the getItemCollection function from CORE:

```
public function getItemCollection()
    {
        if (is_null($this->_items)) {
            $behavior   = $this->getPositionBehavior();

            $this->_customItems = array();
            $this->_items = array();

            if (in_array($behavior, $this->getRuleBasedBehaviorPositions())) {
                $this->_items = $this->_getTargetRuleProducts();
            }
            if (in_array($behavior, $this->getSelectedBehaviorPositions())) {
                foreach ($this->_getLinkProducts() as $id => $item) {
                    $this->_customItems[$id] = $item;
                }
            }
            $this->_orderProductItems();
        }

        return $this->_items;
    }
```

Comment: What do you mean by filter after position ? Filter based on the position attribute ?

Comment: Its  about the upsells product swhere in the grid I have a column "Position". and i want to filter it after that position

Comment: Do you mean getting only the products with a particular position ? For instance, all products with position = 2 ?

Comment: nope. getting all of the products in ascending or descending order after the their position's value

Comment: Which version of Magento are you using ? What is the path to the core file with the `getItemCollection` method ?

Comment: app/code/core/Enterprise/TargetRule/Block/Product/Abstract.php and the version is Magento ver. 1.14.2.2

Comment: Well I'm sorry I don't have Enterprise, can't help you more than what I did

Comment: oke, Thx a lot for the effort, I really appreciate it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not possible, because this method does not return a collection (bad naming choice...). Instead it loads the collection immediately and returns an array with the results.

The simplest solution is to sort this array, using PHP:

```
usort($_productCollection, function($a, $b) {
    if ($a['position'] < $b['position]) {
        return -1;
    } elseif ($a['position'] > $b['position']) {
        return 1;
    }
    return 0;
});
```

or if you are using **PHP 7**:

```
usort($_productCollection, function($a, $b) {
    return $a['position'] <=> $b['position'];
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok so you're talking about sorting and not filtering.

To do so you can use the `setOrder` method:

```
$_productCollection->getSelect()->order('position DESC');
```

Comment: srry im tired, I meant sorting. I tried your code and I get this error message:  Call to a member function setOrder() on array in

Comment: @Chester check my update

Comment: This is what I tried after, but now i get the same message error , except for the function name, now is Call to a member function getSelect() on array in

Comment: @Chester Well I'm not sure where you're getting this collection from but it does not seem to be a collection but an array that's the issue

Comment: I updated my post. Can u check it. Also it is an enterprise magento edition.